# Access: Data Type Mismatch using boolean function in query criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a VBA function `IsValidEmail()` that returns a boolean.  I have a query that calls this function: `Expr1: IsValidEmail([E-Mail])`.  When I run the query, it shows -1 for True and 0 for False.  So far so good.

Now I want to filter the query to only show invalid emails.  I'm using the Query Designer, so I just add a value of `0` to the Criteria field.  This gives me a "Data Type Mismatch" error.  So does `"0"` (with quotes) and False.  How am I supposed to specify criteria for a boolean function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the fact that some of the records in my table have a null E-Mail.  My query has a where condition to exclude null E-Mail records, so when I ran it with no condition on the IsValidEmail column my function was only called for records with a non-null E-Mail.  However, when I added the condition on IsValidEmail it called the function for every record, and the error came from trying to pass null to a function expecting a string.

Another way to say all that:

```
SELECT [E-Mail],
       IsValidEmail([E-Mail]) <--Executed only for rows matching where clause
FROM   Contacts
WHERE  IsValidEmail([E-Mail]) = False; <-- Gets executed for all rows
```

Changing my query expression from `IsValidEmail([E-Mail])` to `IsValidEmail(nz([E-Mail],"X"))` resolved the issue.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you check the definition of IsValidEmail() so that it definitely returns a Boolean instead of a variant. If it's defined as Public Function IsValidEmail(...) it should be changed to Public Function IsValidEmail(...) As Boolean. You could also have changed it to use a variant for the passed email address so that it could handle Nulls internally without needing to call Nz() for every row you pass to it. This would also make it possible to add an optional parameter that gives you the choice of counting a Null email as valid or invalid.

Comment: ...continuing on from that, to me, a Null email is not an invalid email address, just a missing one, and that's not the same thing. But whether or not you agree depends on how you are using it. BTW, parsing an email address for validity is actually quite a complex process and even if it's text is well-formed, that still doesn't mean it's actually a valid address in the sense that it won't bounce.

Comment: @Fenton: Thanks for the feeback.  I was looking for a way to make by function (which is explicitly defined as boolean btw) accept nulls and handle them internally.  I will implement your variant paramter approach.  And I am well aware of the complexities of email address validation - there are enough questions on SO about that already so I wasn't going to get into that here.

Answer (score 2):

For a boolean column, "0" will definitely give you the "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error.  However, 0 or False without quotes should work. I don't understand why they are generating the same error.

See if you can produce a working query by editing the SQL directly.  Create a new query, switch to SQL View and paste in this statement (replacing YourTableName with the name of your table).

```
SELECT IsValidEmail([E-Mail]) AS valid_email
FROM YourTableName
WHERE IsValidEmail([E-Mail]) = False;
```

Will your query run without error when you create it that way?

**Update**:  Since that query also produced the same error, all I can suggest is trying this one without any criteria.

```
SELECT
    IsValidEmail([E-Mail]) AS valid_email,
    TypeName(IsValidEmail([E-Mail])) AS type_of_valid_email
FROM YourTableName;
```

However, that seems like a long shot because you already told us your earlier attempt without criteria ran without error.  If this doesn't identify the problem, would you consider emailing me a stripped down copy of your database?  Let me know if you're interested and I'll give you my email address.

Comment: I copy/pasted your query into SQL view, changed the table name, and executed.  Same error.

Comment: I figured it out while mocking up an example to send you.  Thanks!